# Is talking about the iPhone SDK 3.0 prohibited?

Tags: discussion, questions, iphone

Whenever I ask about the iPhone SDK 3.0, my questions get negative votes with not even a single answer.

One question in particular, [about the functioning of the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369765/how-its-new-stuff-bought-in-the-app-store-integrated-to-my-iphone-app), I ended up deleting and reformulating the question. But the response is always the same. And I have no clue why.

Is there any particular reason why? Are the questions inappropriate, incorrect or prohibited?

Comment: try asking one question at a time rather than 10

Comment: ...and try to be specific...

Answer (score 3):

Clearly I can't speak for everyone, but the reason I wouldn't normally answer the kind of question you linked to is that it's incredibly broad: "How do I use Store Kit?" That kind of query is best answered by reading the documentation. And if you *have* read it and that's what's confused you, then I would expect to see some evidence of that, "Section X in Blah says so-and-so but...?"

I think StackOverflow is best used as a question and answer forum, not as a tutorial or step-by-step guide.

Finally, the development version of iPhone OS is usually covered by an NDA, so, for example, until 9th September you probably shouldn't have been talking publicly about version 3.1. But the public versions are fine.

Comment: +1 for the NDA details. And if people are downvoting because they think any iPhone discussion violates NDA, they're wrong -- we just can't talk about the dev version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe people don't have an answer...?

Not everything you ask is gonna be answered.

Comment: If people don't have an answer, that does not warrant a downvote.